# Writing test classes for a custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, unit-test

I'm having trouble writing the tests for the following custom controller. I'm new to SF and I'm simply displaying a list of "future" events on a VF page. It does exactly what I need and I would like to post to production BUT I need to write the tests before. Can some one please help. I don't really know what I should test for. Thanks in advance.

== controller ==

```
public with sharing class FutureEvents {
    Transient public List<Event__c> events;
    public List<Event__c> getEvents() {
        if(events == null) {
            events = [SELECT Name, Event_Website__c FROM Event__c WHERE Event_Start_Date__c > TODAY AND Featured_Event__c = TRUE];
        }
        return events;
    }
}
```

== VF page ==

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
    sidebar="false"
    controller="FutureEvents"
    doctype="html-5.0"
    standardStylesheets="false"
>
<ul>
    <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="event">
        <li>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!event.Event_Website__c}" target="_parent" rendered="{!!ISBLANK(event.Event_Website__c)}">{!event.Name}</apex:outputLink>
            <apex:outputText value="{!event.name}" rendered="{!ISBLANK(event.Event_Website__c)}"></apex:outputText>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
</apex:page>
```

== Test ==

```
@isTest
public class FutureEventsTests{
    static testMethod void dtTests() {
        // based on salesforce documentation
        // http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

        // prepatre data
        List<Event__c> evs = new List<Event__c>{};

            for(Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Event__c e = new Event__c(Name = 'Event ' + i, 
                                          Featured_Event__c = True);
                evs.add(e);
            }

        // Start the test
        test.startTest();

        // Insert the Events records
        insert evs;

        // Stop the test
        test.stopTest();

        List<Event__c> insertedEvents = [SELECT Name FROM Event__c WHERE Featured_Event__c = TRUE];

        // Instantiate a new controller

        Integer i = 0;
        for (Event__c e : insertedEvents) {
            System.assertEquals('Event ' + i, e.Name);
            System.assert(True, e.Featured_Event__c);
            i++;
        }


    } // testMethod
} // class
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example have you read the section on "Test Methods and Visualforce Controllers" here http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods? You might find people are reluctant to write your code for you if you haven't tried it yet yourself.

Comment: :) I should have included that too! I just updated the question to include what I wrote

Comment: I guess the big problem I have is I don't really know what to test for. The controller is not doing anything, just retrieving some records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test methods should cover only the subject matter. In this case, the subject matter is the controller.

Your test method should simply make sure it returns events, like this:

```
static testMethod void test() {
    FutureEvents fe = new FutureEvents();
    Test.startTest();
    Event__c[] events = fe.getEvents();
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, events);
}
```

It doesn't matter what the name of the event is, or how many there are, or anything else, since all you're doing is verifying that it returns a list, and not null.

Testing the events would be a subject matter for a trigger test method, or some other case. All you need to do is verify the controller is functional, and this test proves that.

Comment: I get an an error here: 'static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @AndyHitchings See [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87515) for how to resolve.